# BizTalk 2009 MQ Series Adepater with WebSphere MQ 7.0

Tags: biztalk, ibm-mq, biztalk-2009

We are in the process of upgrading IBM Websphere MQ Series from V6.x to V7.x.

Currently our BizTalk application servers are integrated  to IBM Websphere MQSeries  server to read messages from remote queue through BizTalk 2009 MQSeries adapter.

We would like to know whether our current BizTalk 2009 MQSeries adapter needs any updates to connect to new 7.x version of IBM Websphere MQ Series server.

Below are our BizTalk and IBM MQ series Server configurations

1. BizTalk 2009 (Windows 2003 64 bit) with MQ Series Adapter.
2. IBM Websphere MQSeries Server (V6.0.2.7  with Windows 2003 32 bit)

Comment: "read messages from remote queue" ??? You can't do that.

Comment: thanks nitgeek for ur answer. i want to know that upgrading MQ Series to version 7.x has any change required to existing biztalk 2009 connection using the MQSeries adapter. thanks.

Comment: FWIW we used BTS 2009 with v7.0 (and 7.0.1.0 refresh pack) client to a 7.0 server without issue, however, we use the MQSC adapter (i.e. installing MQ client on the BTS Servers, non COM+ - our MQ Server is Unix). And FWIW we are now using BTS 2010 successfully with the transactional 7.5 client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Infocenter for each of the releases, there is a section on version-to-version changes.  There are several related to Windows.  Please see the Infocenter for the appropriate version:

[V6.0 to V7.5 Changes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi67530_.htm)
[V6.0 to V7.1 Changes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi67101_.htm)

There is a V7.0 Infocenter but at this point, everyone should be migrating to V7.5 preferably, or V7.1 at the earliest, due to the security enhancements and other features.